# Why Accessors in not called in my laravel app?

Tags: php, laravel, orm, laravel-8, accessor

I was not happy with the default created_at date format in my database table so I decided to create Accessors which will simply change my date format. But I found out that Accessors is not running. I tried to use it on another column but it doesn't change my output. then I use dd($value) so it can stop in accessor but I found out that it didn't. I am getting my data from the database and the accessor is been bypassed.

my accessor in model class is:

```
 public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
    {
        dd($value);
    }
```

But it does not effect anything as I am getting my output of :

```
$case=Allcase::with('donner')->get();
        print_r($case);
```

and also no effect to created_at:

[image]

Comment: Don't use `dd()`, use the proper code `return $value`, or `return $this->created_at`. Also, consider renaming your method to `public function getCreatedAtFormattedAttribute() { return $this->created_at->format('Y-m-d'); }`, then, call `Allcase::first()->created_at_formatted`; this way, you don't override any logic around the `created_at` column, since there is a lot that happens behind the scenes with that column.

Comment: @TimLewis but it only works with first(). It does not work if I get all records, and I have to retrieve all records and pass them to view. If I use get() then it does not include created_at_formated field.

Comment: It won't; accessors are not included by default, but they are still available. If you use `->get()`, then you can loop, like `foreach(Alllcase::get() as $allCase)`, then `$allcase->created_at_formatted` is available and will work. Please review the documentation for Accessors: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the actual attribute value in this way

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute()
{
    return Carbon::parse($this->attributes['created_at'])->format('Y-m-d');

}
```

Now, you can get your data and print it. You can show the differences now

```
$case = Allcase::with('donner')->get();
print_r($case);
```

Comment: Actually, I tried this first but It didn't work. Not only this but also none of my accessor work. I uppercase the string from the name field to check but no effect at all. I have also a foreign key function in my model which works perfectly. but these accessors are not

Comment: Look changes in Laravel 9, https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor